# Child div not clickable with z-index

Tags: html, css

child div not working with z-index : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/408/)

The next button is not clickable .

Any idea ?

```
<div class="animated" ng-class="{'overlay' :overLay, 'install' : install, 'request' : request, 'flash' : animate, 'add-remove' :add}">

    <div class="tooltip-content clearfix animated" >
        <div class="lesson-tour-step__header">شروع</div>


        <div class="steps">
            <a class="btn next-step-btn" href="#" ng-if="btnStepStart" ng-click="steps('start')">next  </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `pointer-events:none;` from `.tooltip-content`.

Comment: thanks a million , what a miss .
put that below please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have `pointer-events: none;`  remove it and it will work properly

```
.tooltip-content {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 177px;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2fa0ec;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #2a3035;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-left: -180px;
       padding: 1.5em;

    text-align: right;

    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s, transform 0.4s ease 0s;
    width: 360px;
    z-index:999999 !important;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/414/)**

Answer (score 1):

pointer-events: none

The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.